# Next.js multisite plugin context is not returning rewrite path

Tags: multisite, nextjs

I am using `next.js` multisite plugin

> https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/21/sitecore-headless-development/the-next-js-multisite-add-on.html

I have configured 2 sites in `env.sites`, `cft` and `mpoc`. JSS app name is `cft`. I have created `_site_cft` and `_site_mpoc` rewrite paths under `src/pages`. But, the app always fetches `cft` layout data even for `mpoc` hostname. I have turned on the debugger on middleware and added some logs. The middleware is redirecting correctly but `getstaticpaths` context in `[[,,path]].tsx` file not containing site rewrite path. Due to this, page props factory always calling `layoutdata` of `cft`

[image]

[image]

Will be great if someone can help on this

Thanks

Comment: Why did you create rewrite paths? The multisite module encapsulates all this, you shouldn't have to be manually creating anything. The `[[...path]].tsx` should be in the root of the `pages` folder.

Comment: @RichardSeal OMG. Thank you very much i am doing it all wrong.  But i have one more problem, i am getting CORS errors on _devPagesManifest.json for hostnames other than default one. How to resolve that? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we can mark this as answered:

In the muiltisite module, you don't need to manually create the `_site_<sitename>` folders, the SDK will create those for you. You need to make sure that the `[[...path]].tsx` file is in the root of your `/src/pages` folder.

This will then execute correctly and the middleware will handle the rewrites for multiple sites.

Comment: I'd like to second @bala-grorrepati on the COSR issue on hostnames other than default one (`PUBLIC_URL` env. variable). It tries to reach _devPagesManifest with main hostname while the initial request came for a secondary hostname then CORS errors and loops into refresh cycle

Troubleshooting guide is not very descriptive on resolution, it says what we should do at a high level without explaining how exactly. It is clear we must allow cors for all the secondary domain how exactly to do that? Access-Control-Allow-Origin allowed only once and it's not clear how to pass few hostnames through it